# Qt C++ Modulo Operator Failing

Tags: c++, qt, math, modulo

This is hopefully a really simple issue that I am overlooking. I am writing in C++ on Qt and I am working on ciphers. I have to use the `%26` in order to get them working. I tested this: `qDebug() << (6-18)%26;` and according to the internet and math, it should produce me with the number 14, right? No. I get -12 which is what 6-18 is, so I don't know if the modulo isn't being applied of what. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @incBrain Thank you, it worked! Should I delete the post?

Comment: @NicholasJohnson You can delete it if you wish, or you can just leave it and it may be marked as a dupe, which might still help people searching for it in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on this:
6-18 = -12

When I divide:
-12/26 = 0.46

With modulus = 4

I Hope this help you.